# WCSession is never paired or installed on Apple Watch

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I have been trying to use `WCSession` on WatchKit 2.0 and iOS 9 but it does not seem to work.

I keep getting the same error message:
`Error Domain=WCErrorDomain Code=7005` "Device is not paired." `UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Device is not paired., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Pair the device with a Watch.}`

In the App Watch Interface I added `WCSessionDelegate` and in `awakeWithContext: initialize` the session like this:

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
    WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
    session.delegate = self;
    [session activateSession];
}
```

In the iOS app I added `WCSessionDelegate` and initialized in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` the same way but it is never paired on either location.

The Apple Watch IS Paired it just does not work with `WCSession`

And when I call the following I got the error.

```
[session sendMessage:userInfo replyHandler:^(NSDictionary *reply) {
    NSLog(@"AW open parent: Done");
   }
   errorHandler:^(NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"AW open parent ERROR: %@",error.description);
    }
];
```

Any ideas what is going on?

UPDATE:

1. I restarted all devices + Xcode
2. Apple Watch is 100% paired
3. Delegates are set and session is activated
4. iOS app does not starts at all but it works more or less with openParentApplication: reply: (The app supposed to do some heavy lifting but it terminates the app in the middle of it even though it is beginBackgroundTask is used)

Comment: Do you use a GM version of Xcode?

Comment: @DmitryGutsulyak It is the final 7A220, released 16 September

Comment: Try to switch on/off "Show App on Apple Watch" in "My Watch" application on iPhone.

Comment: @DmitryGutsulyak I tried that, thanks, but it dod not change anything. I managed to fix the openParentApplication: route, it was silent crash because of an overreleased!? CGColorSpaceRef

Comment: The only thing I didn't catch is how you use `openParentApplication:` that available only from iPhone extension in watchOS 1 and `WCSession` that available only on Watch under watchOS 2.

Comment: I mentioned openParentApplication: because it proved that the two devices can communicate with each other so the not paired should be coming from somewhere else. It is very annoying because it seems I have to use a depreciated method for communication.

Comment: probably your best bet is to file a bug with Apple including a sample project where this reproduces. If you do so, report back here with the radar number so that any perusing Apple engineers can easily find it.

Comment: @ccjensen Probably that would be the best. I'll put together a sample project and upload it to here  as well